# refactor library to Lazy-Evaluation WITHOUT refactoring call site

Tags: c++, lambda, c++17, refactoring, lazy-evaluation

How to change code from normal initialization to lazy initialization **without** refactoring user's code (caller)?

[MSVE](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cf07268297020cf1)

I have a library class.

From profiling, there is a sad bottleneck at `str` parameter evaluation below.

```
struct Library{
    static bool debugFlag;//<== user-define. Its value is changed often. 
    template<class F1> static void doTask(const std::string& str,F1&& task){
        if(debugFlag){
            /// Do very expensive thing that need "str" 
            //     (e.g. for profiling).
        }
        task();
    }
};
bool Library::debugFlag=false;
```

^ By design, the real value of `std::string str` is needed if and only if `Library::debugFlag` is true.
However, we can't know in advance.  Its value also changes often.

Here is an example of user's code that call the above `Library::doTask()`.

```
//vvvvvvv user code (we can't modify) vvvvvvvvv
int main(){///
    Library::debugFlag=true;  //<== user-define. Its value is changed often. 
    int var=5; //<== user-define. Its value is changed often. 
    int var2=6; //<== user-define. Its value is changed often. 
    Library::doTask(
        "a label for this task id="+std::to_string(var)+" fork custom="+std::to_string(var2)
        ,[](){}
    );
}
```

User can create string in any way, but it is guaranteed to appear in 1 expression.

I heard that lambda is the way of lazy evaluation, but how to do lazy evaluation without refactoring user code?

If possible, I still want to avoid using macro.

Hopefully, as a workaround, there might be a way to 1. implicitly create lambda from expression, or 2. suggest the compiler to check `Library::debugFlag` before evaluate the `std::string str`.

Comment: I don't think you can do anything productive here if you're not allowed to change the invocations. Is constructing a string really that bad? (Beyond the repeated use of `std::string::operator+`)

Comment: @Botje :: How sad.  Yes, it is really that bad.  My unfortunate. Thanks.

Comment: @cppBeginner It seems to me like a "how can I fix this without fixing this"-type issue. Note that e.g. `Library::doTask(lazy << "a label ..." << var << " ... " << var2, [](){})` is feasible to do (mostly) lazy eval (with a properly defined `lazy` object). - but really, what you wanted here is lambda expressions.

Comment: @lorro ::    `Lazy<<` is very interesting approach.  Thanks.

Comment: The thing is, the string is created from the user side (before entering into the function), nothing you can do from the library side. So if you can't modify the user code, what you want seems impossible to me.

Comment: @Fareanor :: Thanks.  To know that it is impossible is useful.